# GHS INTEGRITY delay between uboot bootelf and the target beginning execution?

Tags: greenhills

When running an INTEGRITY 178 ARINC/APEX image on a PPC SBC, using uboot console we load the program with tftpboot and initiate execution with bootelf.  (We actually enter an extra RETURN after the bootelf command so that the INTEGRITY copyright banner displays on the uboot console when the target begins execution.)

Question:  Why is there about a 12 second delay between the bootelf command and the apparent beginning of execution of the application portion of the image?  And if there is a way to reduce this delay?

Potential sources uboot, POST, GHNet network initialization, other sources...?

Thanks,
mlk

Answer (score 0):

For us, the filesystem initialization is the longest delay at boot.

Comment: Yes I could see that being a contribution.Our target image does not include a filesystem, does not r/w data flash, ....  That is why in original post I thought might be POST of some sort or maybe GHNet TCP/IP stack initialization.